# Can we tell our origin based on foot phenotype?

Tags: biology

This suggest that someone from european lineages, can tell its origin from the shape of its feet. Does it really work?

[image]

Comment: This seems to provide a possible explanation: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1xupe6/is_there_any_validity_to_this_image/ (and perhaps documents notability at least?).